# My flink job keeps reading the same bytes over and over

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a flink job that always falls behind no matter how much resource i throw at it.

I am using flink 1.15.2 but the problem happened on 1.14.[4|6]

Here is how i am connecting to the input stream:

```
val properties = getInputProperties(kafkaReadConfig)

val byteArrayDeserializer = new AbstractDeserializationSchema[Array[Byte]]() {
  override def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = bytes
}

val flinkKafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[Array[Byte]](kafkaReadConfig.topic, byteArrayDeserializer, properties)

val res = env.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer).setParallelism(kafkaReadConfig.parallelism).name(kafkaReadConfig.topic)
```

Just doing a simple FlatMap, i see the same bytes being read over and over again.  My pipeline ends in a print(for debugging)

```
inputStream.setParallelism(1)
  .flatMap(lookForDupes).setParallelism(1)
  .print()
```

Is there something dumb i am doing?  Do i need to verify the packet was processed somehow?

Looking for some way to mark the block as read at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected the task manager logs for clues? This can happen if the job is in a `fail -> recover -> fail again` loop.